# Input layer 0 of sequence is incompatible with the layer - CNNs

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, valueerror

I am trying to create a CNN model using hyperparameterization for image classification. When I run the code I receive the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(32, 32, 32, 3)

How to fix the error? Here is the whole code pasted below:

```
# first we create our actual code which requires the arguments, units, activation, dropout, lr:
def build_model(hp):
  model = ks.Sequential([
  # adding first conv2d layer
  ks.layers.Conv2D(
            #Let's tune the filters, kernel_size, activation function.
            filters = hp.Int("conv_1_filter", min_value=1,max_value=100, step = 16),
            kernel_size = hp.Choice("conv_1_kernel", values = [3,5]),
            activation = hp.Choice("conv_1_activation", ["relu", "tanh", "softmax"]),
            input_shape = (32,32,32,3) 
   ),
  # adding second conv2d layer
  ks.layers.Conv2D(
            #Let's tune the filters, kernel_size, activation function.
            filters = hp.Int("conv_2_filter", min_value=1,max_value=50, step = 16),
            kernel_size = hp.Choice("conv_2_kernel", values = [3,5]),
            activation = hp.Choice("conv_2_activation", ["relu", "tanh", "softmax"]),
            input_shape = (32,32,32,3)
  )])
  model.add(layers.Flatten())

  # Let's tune the number of Dense layers.
  for i in range(hp.Int("num_dense_layers", 1, 3)):
    model.add(
        layers.Dense(
            # Let's tune the number of units separately
            units = hp.Int(f"units_{i}", min_value=1, max_value = 100, step = 16),
            activation = hp.Choice("activation", ["relu", "tanh", "softmax"])
        ))

  if hp.Boolean("dropout"):
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate = 0.25))

  model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))
  learning_rate = hp.Float("lr", min_value = 1e-4, max_value = 1e-2, sampling="log")
  model.compile(
      optimizer = ks.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate),
      loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
      metrics = ["accuracy"]
  )  
  return model

  build_model(keras_tuner.HyperParameters())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error due the input shape mismatch.

Here i have implemented the hypermodel on the mnist fashion dataset which contains images of shape (28,282,1).

```
def build_model(hp):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
  # adding first conv2d layer
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            #Let's tune the filters, kernel_size, activation function.
            filters = hp.Int("conv_1_filter", min_value=1,max_value=100, step = 16),
            kernel_size = hp.Choice("conv_1_kernel", values = [3,5]),
            activation = hp.Choice("conv_1_activation", ["relu", "tanh", "softmax"]),
            input_shape = (28,28,1) 
   ),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
      pool_size=hp.Choice('pooling_1',values=[2,3])),

  # adding second conv2d layer
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            #Let's tune the filters, kernel_size, activation function.
            filters = hp.Int("conv_2_filter", min_value=1,max_value=50, step = 16),
            kernel_size = hp.Choice("conv_2_kernel", values = [3,5]),
            activation = hp.Choice("conv_2_activation", ["relu", "tanh", "softmax"]),
            input_shape = (28,28,1)
  )])
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
      pool_size=hp.Choice('pooling_2',values=[2,3])),

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

  if hp.Boolean("dropout"):
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.25))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))
  learning_rate = hp.Float("lr", min_value = 1e-4, max_value = 1e-2, sampling="log")
  model.compile(
      optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate),
      loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
      metrics = ["accuracy"]
  )  
  return model
```

By providing the correct shape you will not get any error.

For more details, Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/efdbbafda3ae79c7e527b088b4f4b5fc) and this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner). Thank You!